# C++ Access protected constructor of parent

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

The following code attempts to access the constructor of A instead of the constructor of B, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62351449/exposing-protected-constructor-in-parent-class). Without explicitly declaring a constructor for B, `B(int x): A(x) {}`, is it possible to let B use the constructor of A? With many parameters and overloads, explicitly redeclaring each constructor of A in its subclasses gets very verbose.

```
struct A {
protected:
    A(int x) {}
};

struct B: public A {
public:
    using A::A;
};

int main()
{
    auto b = new B(5);
    return 0;
}
```

->

```
main.cpp:25:21: error: ‘A::A(int)’ is protected within this context
   25 |     auto b = new B(5);
      |                     ^
```

Comment: Is there a reason a perfect forwarding variadic template constructor wouldn't work?

Comment: Do you mean something like `template <typename... Args>` ... `A::A(Args...)`? I'm not familiar with perfect forwarding constructors

Comment: This seems to work: `template <typename... Args>
    B(Args&&... args) : A(std::forward<Args>(args)...) { }`. A bit verbose, but at least it's constant.

Comment: It would be simpler to redeclare the constructor of `A` as `public`.   One of the required effects of making it `protected` is preventing it being called directly from outside the class hierarchy (e.g. by `main()` in your case).    Adding a forwarding constructor to `A` to work around `protected` access that is specified by `A` is simply self-flagellation.

Comment: The motivation is that `A` is abstract, without having to define any pure virtual methods and implementing them in `B` to make it so.